# shiny download csv or excel depending on radioButton

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Download as excel or csv based on user input. The code works only for the pre-selected value in radioButtons. As below it works for csv, because `selected = "csv"`. If it is changed to xlsx it only works for xlsx. The user should be able to select and both options should be possible.

Maybe the value is cached and I need to force an update somehow.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h4("Download data"),
    wellPanel(
        fluidRow(
            column(4, radioButtons("dl_data_file_type", "Format",
                                   choices = c(excel = "xlsx",
                                               csv = "csv"),
                                   selected = "csv")),
            column(5),
            column(3, downloadButton("dl_data_dwnld_bttn"))
        )))


server <- function(input, output) {
    output$dl_data_dwnld_bttn <- {
        downloadHandler(
            filename = stringr::str_c(Sys.Date(), " Palim.", input$dl_data_file_type),
            content = function(file){
                x <- iris

                if ( input$dl_data_file_type == "xlsx")  {
                    writexl::write_xlsx(x, file)}
                else if ( input$dl_data_file_type == "csv") {
                    readr::write_csv(x, file)}

            })}}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The error is that the excel file still ends with .csv and cannot be opened by excel.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure ? I don't see any error.

Comment: No I have not tried. I think I understand now. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a reactive value in the `filename` argument. In this case, you have to set `filename` as a function:

```
filename = function(){
  stringr::str_c(Sys.Date(), " Palim.", input$dl_data_file_type)
}
```